# SecPKCS12Import leak under arc?

Tags: iphone

I was found memory leaks by iOS instruments on all SecPKCS12Import lines of that code under arc:

```
    SecCertificateRef certRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trustRef, 0);
    CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certRef);
    NSData *data = (__bridge_transfer NSData *) SecCertificateCopyData(certRef);
    NSURL *indexURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"cert1" withExtension:@"p12"];
    NSData *localP12 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:indexURL];
    NSMutableDictionary * options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *password = ///
    [options setObject:password forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];
    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef) localP12,(__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options, &items);
    if (securityError == noErr) { };/// good } else { //bad }
    CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    CFArrayRef certificates =
    (CFArrayRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,kSecImportItemCertChain);
    SecCertificateRef localCert = (SecCertificateRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(certificates,0);
    CFDataRef dataLocal = SecCertificateCopyData(localCert);
    NSData *local = (__bridge NSData *)dataLocal;
    //NSLog(@"local:%@",local);
    NSURL *indexURLmac3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"cert2" withExtension:@"p12"];
    NSData *localP12mac3 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:indexURLmac3];
    NSMutableDictionary * optionsMac3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *passwordMac3 = //
    [optionsMac3 setObject:passwordMac3 forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];
    CFArrayRef itemsMac3 = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef) localP12mac3, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)optionsMac3, &itemsMac3);
    if (securityError == noErr) { };/// good } else { //bad }
    CFDictionaryRef identityDictMac3 = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(itemsMac3, 0);
    CFArrayRef certificatesMac3 =
    (CFArrayRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDictMac3, kSecImportItemCertChain);
    SecCertificateRef localCertMac3 = (SecCertificateRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(certificatesMac3,0);
    CFDataRef dataLocalMac3 = SecCertificateCopyData(localCertMac3);
    NSData *localMac3 = (__bridge NSData *)dataLocalMac3;
    NSURL *indexURLwebcob3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"cert3" withExtension:@"p12"];
    NSData *localP12wwebcob3 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:indexURLwebcob3];
    NSMutableDictionary * optionsWebcob3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *passwordWebcob3 = //
    [optionsWebcob3 setObject:passwordWebcob3 forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];
    CFArrayRef itemsWebcob3 = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef) localP12wwebcob3, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)optionsWebcob3, &itemsWebcob3);
    if (securityError == noErr) { };/// good } else { //bad }
    CFDictionaryRef identityDictWebcob3 = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(itemsWebcob3, 0);
    CFArrayRef certificatesWebcob3 =
    (CFArrayRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDictWebcob3,
                                     kSecImportItemCertChain);
    SecCertificateRef localCertWebcob3 = (SecCertificateRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(certificatesWebcob3,0);
    CFDataRef dataLocalWebcob3 = SecCertificateCopyData(localCertWebcob3);
    NSData *localWebcob3 = (__bridge NSData *)dataLocalWebcob3;
    if ([data isEqualToData:local] || [data isEqualToData:localMac3] || [data isEqualToData:localWebcob3]) trust = YES;

    CFRelease(certSummary);
    CFRelease((CFDataRef) dataLocal);
    CFRelease((CFDataRef) dataLocalMac3);
    CFRelease((CFDataRef) dataLocalWebcob3);
```

where i'm wrong?

Comment: You could at least format your code nicely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. That code is really hard to follow. You seem to be doing three different PKCS12 imports, you may want to make that a single method that's called three times. Just saying.

Anyway, without even following your code I know what the issue may be - because I have seen this before. The Security methods you are using follow the [CoreFoundation memory management patterns defined here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html). More than once I have found the PKCS12 identity import process leaking because someone did not realize that, or thought that bridge casts to ARC would just make it work.

But here is what you should look at - in addition to whatever Instruments is trying to tell you, of course:

- You need to release the items passed as the last argument to `SecPKCS12Import` (the CFArrayRef in the documentation). Look at [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html) for guidance.
- I see something even more obvious - you are calling `CFArrayCreate` without a corresponding release.

Comment: The ARC transition guide also provides some guidance on using ARC with CoreFoundation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: perfect explanation, tnx. sorry for code, no time to formatting, i just copy/paste